# (KNN ) row compute use outer DataFrame on pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, knn, pyspark

**question**

**my data structure is like this:**

```
train_info:(over 30000 rows)
----------
odt:string (unique)
holiday_type:string
od_label:string
array:array<double> (with variable length depend on different odt and holiday_type )
useful_index:array<int>  (length same as vectors)
...(other not important cols)

label_data:(over 40000 rows)
----------
holiday_type:string
od_label: string
l_origin_array:array<double> (with variable length)
...(other not important cols)

my expected result is like this(length same with train_info):
--------------
odt:string
holiday_label:string
od_label:string
prediction:int
```

**my solution is like this:**

```
if __name__=='__main __'
        loop_item = train_info.collect()
        result = knn_for_loop(spark, loop_item,train_info.schema,label_data)
        ----- do something -------
```

```
def knn_for_loop(spark, predict_list, schema, label_data):
    result = list()
    for i in predict_list:
        # turn this Row col to Data Frame  and  join  on  label data 
        # across to this row data pick label data array data
        predict_df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([i]).toDF(schema) \
            .join(label_data, on=['holiday_type', "od_label"], how='left') \
            .withColumn("l_array",
                     UDFuncs.value_from_array_by_index(f.col('l_origin_array'), f.col("useful_index"))) \
            .toPandas()
        # pandas execute
        train_x = predict_df.l_array.values
        train_y = predict_df.label.values
        test_x = predict_df.array.values[0]
        test_y = KNN(train_x, train_y, test_x)

        result.append((i['odt'], i['holiday_type'], i['od_label'], test_y))
    return result
```

it's worked but is really slow, I estimate each row need 18s.

in R language  I can do this easily using *do* function:

train_info%>%group_by(odt)%>%do(.,knn_loop,label_data)

**something my tries**

I tried to join them before use,and query them when I compute, but the data is too large to run (these two df have 400 million rows after join and It takes up 180 GB disk space on hive and query really slowly).
I tried to use pandas_udf, but it only allows one pd.data.frame parameter and slow).

I tried to use UDF, but UDF can't receive data frame obj.

I tried to use spark-knn package  ,but I run with error,may be my  offline 
 installation is  wrong .

thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi I feel there is issue in data distribution of you data frame see .

https://towardsdatascience.com/the-art-of-joining-in-spark-dcbd33d693c

Comment: this article really improve my knowledge of join , but seems can't solve my question.thanks~